# TypeError: stop() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Currently, I'm trying to modify the baxter Joint Trajectory Client to direct use the left arm to perform the hard-coded position, instead of asking the user to add in the argument to choose the arms. After I done my modification and run the code it shows me : `TypeError: stop() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)` *

Of course, I had run the server node at same time.

It's there any part of my program was wrong or it's due to the server node was required to get the argument at the same time?

This is the [example](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Joint_Trajectory_Client_-_Code_Walkthrough) in the Baxter wiki.
And this is my program node link:[https: //drive.google.com/open?id=0B6JF01xXRuNbZ0JqWG1WMGNsUWM](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6JF01xXRuNbZ0JqWG1WMGNsUWM)

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236906/typeerror:-stop()-takes-exactly-3-arguments-(1-given)/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting [rospy documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown),

> rospy.on_shutdown(h)
>
> Register handler to be called when
> rospy process begins shutdown. h is a
> function that takes no arguments. You
> can request a callback using
> rospy.on_shutdown() when your node is
> about to begin shutdown. This will be
> invoked before actual shutdown occurs,
> so you can perform service and
> parameter server calls safely.
> Messages are not guaranteed to be
> published.

Isn't your callback method expecting 3 arguments `(self, position, time)`? But the method `h()` takes no arguments (argument `self` is provided).

When the callback is called, the TypeError is thrown because the callback method is called is called with insufficient number of arguments. And I'm not sure you need those two arguments because you don't use them inside the method anyway.

Inside the Trajectory class, check the `stop()` definition to this :

```
def stop (self):
        self._client.cancel_goal()
```

It will solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-14**:
Hi Janindu,
You answer work for me, and I'm able to run my core.But it just didn't form the position. At my service running terminal it shows :[WARN] [WallTime: 1465966247.239178] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-14**:
0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.

So this is mean that my program didn't send out the data?

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
In your `ylj_joint_traTest.py`, you have commented the following line.

```
#server_up = self._client.wait_for_server(time=rospy.Duration(10.0))#Blocks until the action server connects to this client.
```

What's the reason behind that?

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
this line was not using in my program, that line was used to check the server up if I put in the `try` to take out the error.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
in the actual example there they use this to check the error. So since I done need to take out the error, I just don't use it.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
I think you need that test.
`self._client.wait_for_server()` will block until the action server connects to this client. The error you see now looks like a connection error.
I suggest you uncomment it and check for error. At least it will give us more information.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
it shows that `TypeError: wait_for_server() got an unexpected keyword argument 'time'`

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
I think you have it as

```
server_up = self._client.wait_for_server(time=rospy.Duration(10.0))
```

It should be

```
server_up = self._client.wait_for_server(timeout=rospy.Duration(10.0))
```

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
oh! I found the problem! I had to change the `time=rospy.Duration(10.0)` to `timeout=rospy.Duration(10.0)`. And yes, you are right! I should not comment that line, that line had his purpose! Thank you so much!

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
No worries. Is everything sorted now?

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
Yes! you are right! I made a silly mistake! thank you for your patiently explained and solved my problem!

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
yes, now should be fine.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
Hi, janindu.
Would you mind give your email address to me? You look so good in this area. So if I had any Baxter relate question I can direct ask you. That will save my life.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-15**:
Hey Zero, to be frank I'm a beginner myself. I only heard about ROS in March 2016 (yep, I'm that new) when I started my PhD. And I didn't answer any Baxter related questions here either.
But yeah I'm always willing to help.
janindu1@gmail.com

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-06-15**:
oh...I see. But your explain and answer was really useful for me. I really appreciate it!